# Are there any limitations of Hyper-V inside Windows 8 client compared to Windows Server 2012?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8, windows-server-2012

As the title says - are there any limitations (hardware, software or licensing) of Hyper-V as found in Windows 8 client OS compared to this feature in Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx) (April, 2012) the following is missing from Client Hyper-V (with respect to Server 8):

- Remote FX ability to virtualize GPUs
- live migration of VMs
- Hyper-V Replica
- SR-IOV networking
- virtual Fibre Channel

Comment: And there is one unpleasant additional hardware requirement - your CPU must support SLAT.

Comment: The lack of RemoteFX was a surprise to me (I can't play video/games smoothly). Otherwise the other features seem to be relevant to data center's for the most part, therefore I can live with it.